# VStack's frame size doesn't fill all of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was creating some View using SwiftUI and encountered a weird bug with VStack's frame dimensions. The gradient doesn't fill all of the screen's height. 
Is that just Xcode bug or am I doing something wrong?
[image]

```
struct WelcomeView : View {

    private let colors = [
        Color(red: 29/255, green: 151/255, blue: 108/255),
        Color(red: 147/255, green: 249/255, blue: 185/255)
    ]

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Content here")
        }
        .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors), 
   startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top), cornerRadius: 0)

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post your code in a way that we can help you! It's **not** an Xcode bug - you are doing something wrong. But without actually seeing your code it's very hard to say what.

Comment: Sorry. Edited question with my code.

Comment: Did you try removing the `.frame(width...` and using `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` like shown here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-place-content-outside-the-safe-area ?

Comment: Daniel, thank you so much for your answer! It was right and now everything works just fine. I am just wondering why my option didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the frame I would use spacers on either side of the Text, I cant test it right now, but let me know if that helps.

```
var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Content here")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [colors),
            startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
```

Comment: It kinda helps, but I am left with white spaces on top and bottom of the screen and edgesIgnoringSafeArea doesn't work.

Comment: `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` needs to go after `.background()` not before.

Answer (score 0):

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Content here")
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top), cornerRadius: 0)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

}
```

source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-place-content-outside-the-safe-area

Comment: This is a good solution. Alternatively, you can delete the .frame() all together, and put `HStack { Spacer() }` inside the `VStack`. This will make your view expand horizontally, when the device is rotated. Your choice, as @VViktor's answer is good too.